# Translate instances based on curve radius

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to translate an instance using the manually set curve radius of the curve it's placed on to create a spiral of instances surrounding the curve. Using the previously captured curve radius doesn't actually translate the instances.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As noted in the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/capture_attribute.html), you need to use the *Geometry* output of the *Capture Attribute* node you get the information from for it to have an effect. In your case, you would link it to the *Points* socket of the *Instance on Points* node.

[image]

*Note:* If I'm understanding your intention right, you also probably want to select the *Point* mode of your *Capture Attribute* node (instead of *Spline*), since you presumably want the individual radii of your spline's *control points* to affect the translation. Selecting *Spline* would result in getting only one value (the average radius of your whole curve):

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm not able to reproduce it. Even using the exact same node setup, doesn't produce a result

Comment: I don't know how that's possible. Can you share a screenshot showing the same setup? What Blender version are you on?

Comment: I'm using Blender 3.0.1
Here is an image of the node setup
https://imgur.com/a/2Fqu8Ki

Comment: @PinieP I tried it in 3.0.1 and indeed it doesn't work. Apparently, attributes didn't support instances in 3.0, it was a feature introduced in 3.1, so if you use a newer version of Blender it should work (I was using 3.2 Alpha). Geometry Nodes is still pretty new so things get changed, added and improved all the time so I'd recommend using the latest versions for it if you can.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Updating solved it.